# How to get the sentences in text file and put in to the array list Java?

Tags: java, string, vector, arraylist

Assume the text file contains:

```
He is a boy .
She is sick .
Ali is playing .
We are eating .
The dog is barking .
He and his brother are running .
```

How can I put all the sentences into array list in format:

```
He is
is a 
a boy
boy .
She is
is sick
sick .
```

and so on.

I use array list to avoid keep reading the text file to perform some task is it possible?
Or I need to use vector to do it?

Comment: Yes, use an `ArrayList<String>`. I'd use a Scanner to read the file. Let's see you give it a try first and see what you come up with.

Comment: You have a strange definition of sentence...

Comment: But is it possible to put in the way I stated above into ArrayList? How it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should make it. I didnt test it. and this is a code just for one line, you`ll need something to Scan your input and consume each line;

```
String line = "He is a boy .";
String[] arr = line.split(" ");
ArrayList<String> newLines = ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
  newLines.add(arr[i-1]+" "+arr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Arthur said, you can e.g. use The **[Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)** class for reading the input from file:

```
Scanner fileScanner = null;
try {
    fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("yourtextfile.txt"));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
    // Some additional code for storing the output to an array around here? :]
    System.out.println(fileScanner.nextLine());
}
```

Answer (score -2):

equally if you didn't want to read from a file but instead from user input you could use this

```
ArrayList<String> uInput = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(scan.nextLine().split("\\s+")));
```